# Adiabatic Heating and Cooling

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm currently studying convection currents and the process of adiabatic cooling and heating, but I'm unable to wrap my head around why this happens. The book states that as air rises, there is less pressure and the air expands. This makes sense (it satisfies PV=nRT). I am unable to comprehend why the increased volume actually causes a decrease in temperature. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Dude156

Comment: The ideal gas law alone is insufficient to explain an adiabatic process.  Say you have some parcel of air with volume V, at pressure P, and temperature T. Then, say you suddenly allow it to expand to double the volume. T will decrease. n and R must remain constant, so that means the pressure must have gone to _less_ than half of the original P. You need a [different law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process) to determine how much less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a parcel of air expands, it pushes the surrounding air out and, by doing that, it performs some work. Since the process is assumed to be adiabatic, i.e., no heat is added to the system, the energy for this work has to come from the internal energy of the expanding air parcel.

In an ideal gas, the internal energy is comprised of the kinetic energies of its molecules and the average kinetic energy defines gas temperature. Therefore, assuming the ideal gas model, the reduction of the internal energy of the air parcel should lead to the reduction of the average the kinetic energy of its molecules and the reduction of its temperature.